# Cannot find TestFlight Internal Testing Tab in itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, internal

Apple recently changed their TestFlight portal in iTunesConnect. There I don't see any tab for internal testing. How can I use internal tester to test my app without Apple review.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In iTunesConnect,"iTunes Connect Users" is Internal testing user.

Comment: Does testing start auto for a newly uploaded build ?

Comment: In TestFlight, We have option to download previous build.